# how to separate values inside an xml tag in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

While calling an API I am getting a response in the following format:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<response>
    <status>success</status>
    <ads>&lt;a href='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/clickAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'&gt;&lt;img src='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/getAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</ads>
</response>
```

I am retrieving the whole value inside the tag  and is storing inside a string.Below is its code:

```
 NSString *html = [xml.documentRoot getNamedChild:@"ads"].text;
```

Now I need to separately store the value inside "href" and "img src" of "ads" tag.How to do that?please help..

Answer (score 1):

```
//as the data you have provided

NSString *html =@"&lt;a href='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/clickAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'&gt;&lt;img src='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/getAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'/&gt;&lt;/a&gt";



    NSString *href;
    NSString *img_src;
    NSRange range = [html rangeOfString:@"href=\'"];
    NSString  *tempUrl=[html substringFromIndex:range.location+6];
    NSRange range2 = [tempUrl rangeOfString:@"\'"];
    href=[tempUrl substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range2.location)];

    range = [html rangeOfString:@"img src=\'"];
    tempUrl=[html substringFromIndex:range.location+9];
    range2 = [tempUrl rangeOfString:@"\'"];
    img_src=[tempUrl substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range2.location)];



    NSLog(@"your href is %@ and your img_src is %@",href,img_src);
```

Comment: :thankyou..this is working .But is it applicable to every response in the above format?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert this to proper html format like this:

```
NSString *html = @"&lt;a href='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/clickAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'&gt;&lt;img src='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/getAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;";

NSData *stringData = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
NSAttributedString *decodedString;
decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData
                                                 options:options
                                      documentAttributes:NULL
                                                   error:NULL];

NSString *finalHtml = [decodedString string]; //it will return <a href='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/clickAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'><img src='http://52.7.130.201/oapi/getAd;jsessionid=679E3CFF39C3D7792E7F6915318E3156.soma-i-915abc39'/></a>
```

Then parse from html. It may help

Comment: :you finalHtml string is not returning any value.It is empty

Comment: No, I have checked it. Print html and check, if you are making any mistake. I have added comment line also for finalHtml

Comment: :Actually By using the code ,"NSString *html = [xml.documentRoot getNamedChild:@"ads"].text;"I am already getting the same value you get in "finalHtml".What I need is to separate the values .

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem
- (void) checkForLINK

{

```
NSError *error= NULL;

NSString* htmlString = @" html=<a href='http://52.7.43.135/oapi/clickAd;jsessionid=4373A2D1CC3FAE62BDF57033C385ADC7.soma-i-65e6329b'><img src='http://52.7.43.135/oapi/getAd;jsessionid=4373A2D1CC3FAE62BDF57033C385ADC7.soma-i-65e6329b'/></a>";



NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];



[detector enumerateMatchesInString:htmlString

                           options:0

                             range:NSMakeRange(0, htmlString.length)

                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)

 {

     NSURL * urlStr = result.URL;



     NSLog(@"URL = %@",urlStr);

 }];
```

}